# Converting image to greyscale outputs wrong result

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing, python-imaging-library, grayscale

```
 def desaturate_image(self, image):
    desatimage = Image.new(image.mode, image.size)
    pixellist = []
    print(len(pixellist))
    for x in range(image.size[0]):
        for y in range(image.size[1]):
            r, g, b = image.getpixel((x, y))
            greyvalue = (r+g+b)/3
            greypixel = (int(round(greyvalue)), int(round(greyvalue)), int(round(greyvalue)))
            pixellist.append(greypixel)
    print(pixellist)
    desatimage.putdata(pixellist)
    return desatimage
```

I'm writing a python method to convert the image passed as parameter to greyscale. The result I get is though, not right. Here's the input and output. Where is it wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged numpy when you're using Pillow rather than numpy to do your image work?

Comment: My bad.. I'm sorry

Comment: By the way, do you actually want to create an RGB8 image where the pixels all happen to be grey, instead of just creating an L8 greyscale image (which is simpler to do, and gives you an image a third the size, and that will compress even better)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over the pixels with the wrong dimension first - Pillow images are column-major order. So you want

```
...
for y in range(image.size[1]):
    for x in range(image.size[0]):
...
```

such that your pixel list stores the pixels column-wise.

This gives you

[image]

---

Of course, you could just use the [`.convert`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert) method to get [a greyscale representation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) more easily, which uses the transform mentioned in the docs.

```
image.convert('L')
```

As abarnert mentioned below, this gives you an image actually in greyscale mode (`'L'`) as opposed to your current answer that keeps the image in RGB mode (`'RGB'`) with triply repeated data.

Comment: Why convert to `LA` instead of `L`? Even if there's an alpha channel in the original image (and the fact that it's uploaded here as a .jpg implies there probably isn't), the OP presumably doesn't care about it.

Comment: @abarnert I beat you to it by like 10 seconds!

Comment: Also, maybe worth mentioning that, while `convert` is a whole lot simpler, and more efficient, and just about impossible to get wrong, it does give you an image in greyscale (L) mode instead of an image in truecolor (RGB) mode that just happens to be grey. Which is more likely to be what the OP actually wants, but it's possible that it isn't…

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for the edit, and that is definitely worth noting.

Comment: I knew about convert method, but I wanted to experiment with handwoven algorithms :) Thanks for the help buddy

Comment: The system takes a few minutes to show the answer accepted :) I gave the tick the moment I got it working :) Thanks buddy

Comment: It's annoying that Google and DDG searches always turn up versioned docs for most Python libraries, and usually old ones (mostly 3.1.0 and 4.2.0 for Pillow).

Comment: @abarnert Agreed... I have an extension for Firefox that redirects me to the most recent Python / C++ docs so out of habit I didn't even think to check.

Comment: @miradulo Yeah, I use a greasemonkey script for that, and it works fine for Python itself (so I go to `/3/` instead of `/3.5/`), and a few other things, but for some reason it keeps breaking for the readthedocs and scipy results every few months…